# Decode JWT in python without installing additional packages

Tags: python, jwt

I'm looking for a way to decode a JWT access token in python3 without installing any additional packages like `jwt`. Something like [this](https://www.michev.info/Blog/Post/2140/decode-jwt-access-and-id-tokens-via-powershell) example for PowerShell.

thanks!

Comment: just split the token into 3 parts  and base64url decode the second part (payload) to a JSON string.

Comment: thanks for the hint, went down that after all :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, figured out that it wasn't indeed too hard to do :)

```
payload = access_token.split('.')[1]
# Apply padding. Add = until length is multiple of 4
while len(payload) % 4 != 0:
   payload += "="

decoded_payload = base64.b64decode(payload)
decoded_token = json.loads(decoded_payload.decode("utf-8"))
oid = decoded_token['oid'] # or any other field from the JWT you want to access
```